# During the Korean War, what B-29 crew roles did the abbreviations IVO, CFC, and VC mean?

Tags: military, aircraft, korean-war

I was researching a B-29 [crash](http://www.koreanwar-educator.org/topics/airplane_crashes/b29_okinawa_195201/p_b29_okinawa.htm) that my grandfather was in during the Korean War, and he was listed as the *IVO* on the flight.  I couldn't find what that abbreviation meant, nor could I find some of the others for crewmen on the flight: CFC and VC.  There was an *IP* on the flight, which is an *Instructor Pilot*, so I was wondering if my grandfather was an *Instructor V-something Officer*. Also the crash happened at night, if that's relevant.

Comment: [CFC Gunner](http://www.twinbeech.com/CFCsystem.htm) appears to be central fire control  gunner  [IVO](http://www.koreanwar-educator.org/topics/b29s/p_b29s_losses_damage.htm) is mentioned in this source, without an explanation. IVO is not one of the crew roles listed, but the admins of that site may be able to explain.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace the link you listed re: IVO is actually the same plane :)

Comment: Not sure if this helps but from the USN Glossary (i was unable to locate a US Air Force one)  VC = Composite Aircraft Squadron ,  VO = Observation Plane , CFC = Chief Fire Control.

Comment: @ed.hank I think VC and IVO are different in this context.  My grandfather was a navigator in WWII and fairly distinguished in that field, so I'm thinking IVO would be related to navigation.  Also, from that article, he's listed as having flown six combat and two training missions before the crash, so I'm thinking that flight was his third training mission (as an instructor).

Comment: One definition of IVO I've found that might make sense is "Installation Voting Officer". No clue what such a person would do/

Comment: The Korean War Education site that we've both cited confirmed that CFC is Central Fire Control; they have reached out to an expert for information on IVO.  (I dropped them an email; very responsive people.  Two thumbs up in my book.)

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace you beat me to it -- thanks for reaching out to them. I'm now fairly certain that IVO is actually IV<sub>O</sub> and means Intructor, Radar Observer. I found it in a obscure report, and will post the reference when I have it in front of me. Evidently <sub> doesn't work in comments :/

Comment: Here's the [link](https://books.google.com/books?id=572VCWnwxWIC&lpg=PP9&ots=TnrblJV7YU&dq=radar%20observer%20%22vo%22%20designation&pg=PP9#v=onepage&q=radar%20observer%20%22vo%22%20designation&f=false) I found that references a Vo designation for a B-29 crew.  It's from a medical study on how stressful each job is on the plane (with navigator and radar observer being most stressful).  I haven't found anything related to the VC crew designation.

Answer (score 3):

I reached out to the Korean War Education Site, who were quite courteous and responsive. I will quote their answer below (I have removed personal information since they didn't grant permission to use names).

> Can’t verify but seem to recall that the VO was the radar operator. RO would have been the Radio Operator, thus the V. The “I” would indicate Instructor, so IVO would be the instructor radar operator. Don’t recall ever using the VC designation. It could be a either a command or crew chief position. Rank would help narrow it. I also believe I remember that the crash occurred at night, followed by an explosion the shook our hut. When we saw the flames, everyone who witnessed it agreed that there could be no survivors. We were happily astonished when we learned there were no fatalities. Apparently one of the crew died later.*[The Korean War Educator](http://thekwe.org/home.htm)*